# Firefox - Jagged / Blurry / Fuzzy / Ugly Font Issue - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, firefox, browser, fonts

Problem: Fuzzy text, Blurry text, Ugly text in Firefox (since long, current version being used is v38.0.5) on Windows 7 (fully updated) BUT not in Chrome Browser

Problem occurs in some web-fonts including Roboto on YouTube. Sometimes selecting the problematic text and pressing "Ctrl+Shift+I" to open Inspector magically solves the problem temporarily on the currently loaded page page (but not on the following page).

A random web page that I am using for this screenshot:
zerick.me/?p=58

Firefox screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvXxC.jpg]

Chrome screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxKMo.jpg]

I have disabled hardware acceleration in Firefox and I don't use Cleartype in Windows (Font Smoothing is enabled). But reversing those things don't solve the problem.

Any ideas on what could be the problem and how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the page zoom is 100%? Hit Ctrl+ 0

Comment: Yes, the page zoom is at 100%. Going down or up does not make a difference except on going very high when the text becomes readable but still not smooth.

Comment: Try going to about:config and setting "gfx.direct2d.disabled" to "true", see if that helps?

Comment: "gfx.direct2d.disabled" was already set to "true". I set it to "false" and restarted Firefox. The text got a little bit readable but stil very ugly and the browser's interface text got blurry. So set it back to "true".

Comment: Have you tried to toggle it in conjunction with hardware acceleration?

Comment: Enabled "hardware acceleration" and set "gfx.direct2d.disabled" to "false". That solved the font problem and made the text on the web page similar to how it appears on Chrome and also solved it on YouTube's Roboto inteface in the video player. But that brings back the problems that HW acceleration caused which is ugly interface text and other text on web pages. I also don't like font smoothing which would be the next logical step. I like my fonts sharp. Is there any way to get this done without HW acceleration?

Comment: Try create a new bool value on the config called "layout.paint_rects_separately" and set it to 'true'?

Comment: Reversed the previous changes to how they were. Added the new value. That does not make any difference to the web page or YouTube interface (text on the timer on the player).

Comment: No idea in that case.
Are you using a GPU?

Comment: Default Intel HD. Drivers are updated from Intel's site. In the given example, the body text on Firefox in HW acceleration disabled is thinner and clean while it becomes bolder and less sharper with HW acceleration. I also like it the way it is in Firefox than in Chrome. But the font in the left-menu is really messed up and unreadable.

Comment: Sorry - hopefully someone else will find this and help out. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I was at least able to temporarily solve the problem and see that the problem is related to "hardware acceleration" disabled (from options) with "gfx.direct2d.disabled" set to "true". However, that is something that I need to keep as it is. Since I have seen such kind of a problem with Firefox's text rendering being posted on forums and other places without a clear resolution, it may also help someone else if this gets solved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As discussed in comments:

We can temporarily alleviate the problem by doing the following:

1. Go to about:config
2. Set "gfx.direct2d.disabled" to "True"
3. Disable "hardware acceleration" via the Options menu

Sadly this has some negative repercussions as discussed in the comments, but it's the closest we've got.